# Missing ASP.Net cookies from iOS

Tags: ios, asp.net-mvc, cookies

I'm experiencing some trouble with an ASP.NET MVC 5 application that has been buggering me for a few days.

The application is using Forms Authentication to control whether a user is Authenticated, and Session to keep track of the user's data.

A few of our users are unable to log in, and I have been able to recreate the problem on a collegue's device. We don't know much about the devices with the problems, except that they all seem to be running iOS. I can't seem to nail down the pattern, though, as one user who reported the problem was running 11.2.5, which I am also running myself without trouble. The collegue's device is running 11.3 beta, but I haven't yet heard of any other users with this version, so I'm unable to pin point that as the problem - which also seems unlikely when one of the users with the problem is running 11.2.5.

The issue happens after the users try logging in. After a successful login, the user is redirected to a specific section of the site, where Authentication is required. Requesting any page in this section redirects you to the login page if you are not Authenticated.
Some of the resources that are requested on this page expect to retrieve some data from Session. For some reason, the Session cookie may sometimes be missing, and other times the Authorization cookie is missing.

For the past few days while I have been hunting this, my collegue's device happened to leave out the Session cookie when requesting our Cachemanifest, in which we expect to be able to generate a specific part based on some data from the Session. This caused the generation to fail, which in turn caused the request to fail.
After changing the generation logic to work around this, with a different solution if the Session cookie is missing, my collegue's device has changed its approach; Now, it includes the Session cookie when requesting this resource, but instead leaves out the Authorization cookie in a subsequent request to a different resource, which is still in the section that requires Authorization. This resource happens to be mentioned in the Cachemanifest, and because this next request does not include the Authorizaiton cookie, that request is redirected to the login page, which is interpreted by the Cachemanifest as an error.

As far as I recall, I haven't changed anything else, so I'm really at a loss as to why this devices' behaviour has changed.

Both of these cookies are included in other requests before and after the failing request, and there doesn't seem to be a pattern between what requests is chooses to leave these two cookies out of, or which cookies to leave out. The only thing that is consistent is that the behaviour doesn't change when retrying after clearing the browser data (only after I made my change, which I still don't see how could result in this behaviour).

The site is forcing HTTPS, so I tried setting the Session cookie to Secure, but that didn't seem to make a difference.

I still need to try setting the Authorization cookie to Secure, but I'm not very optimistic there. I also still need to try reverting my changes to see if the old behaviour reappears.

Has anybody experienced similar problems before, or does anybody have any further suggestions? I know I might be a bit sparse on the details, I'd be happy to provide any further details if I'm able.

Thank you in advance :)